# iOS - How to wait to download data on dataTask

Tags: ios, swift

My app is downloading some data from an API and I want to save that data on an array that will be used to populate a table view. But when the table view starts to be build the data isn't downloaded yet and my array is empty.

```
 var recipes: [Recipe] = []

 func getData(completionHandler: @escaping ([Recipe]) -> Void) {
    let urlString = "api_url"

    guard let url = URL(string: jsonURL) else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err)  in

        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            let recipes: [Recipe] = try JSONDecoder().decode([Recipe].self, from: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.recipes = recipes
            }
        } catch {

        }
    }.resume()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.recipes.count
}
```

Comment: After you set the array, reload the table view.

Comment: That's a really common pattern (there is a _ton_ of examples on SO & tutorials on the web). In a nutshell... reload the tableview after assignment.

Comment: You've already added a completion handler to your function, you should be calling the completion handler when you get your results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to reload the tableview. In your `do` block change your code to the following:

```
self.recipes = try JSONDecoder().decode([Recipe].self, from: data)
DispatchQueue.main.async {
     self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call `tableView.reloadData()` after you download and set the recipes:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.recipes = recipes
      self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```